# libconfig- unresolved external on visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libconfig

I'm trying to compile a code with the `libConfig` library on Windows, in Visual Studio.

This is the code:

```
#include "libconfig.hh"
using namespace libconfig;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{

    Config cfg;

    return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the library from [here](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/). On Additional Include Directories, I added the folder with all the sources and headers.

The error I get for that code is:

```
1>LibConfigTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall libconfig::Config::~Config(void)" (__imp_??1Config@libconfig@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>LibConfigTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall libconfig::Config::Config(void)" (__imp_??0Config@libconfig@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\***\visual studio 2010\Projects\LibConfigTest\Debug\LibConfigTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I also compiled the example code and it succeeded, so I looked at the properties, Additional Include Files and compared it to mine and it was the same.

I can't see any other differences between the codes.

I don't know what am I missing and be happy for some guidance on that one.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig/issues/110 could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to also link the library. Maybe the headers have in them some `pragma link` but even in that case you'll have to include the path for the library somehow. Look for Library Directories, C/C++ Additional Include Directories... if there is no pragma link you'll have to add the lib explicitly at Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies. The path to the library will have to be specified at VC Directories | Library Directories.